# Convert Entity to DTO using Model Mapper is falling

Tags: java, dto, modelmapper

How to use `ModelMapper` to convert Entity to DTO when the entity has `OneToMany` relationship with another entity.

I have one Entity Student

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Student{
        private int name;
        private Set<Department> department;
        }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Department{
        private int name;
        }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class StudentDto{
     private int name;
            private Set<DepartmentDto> departmentDto;
    }

  @Getter
    @Setter
    public class DepartmentDto{
     private int name;
           private int name;
    }
```

I am using  the below method to convert Entity to DTO:-

```
private List<StudentDto> convertToDto(List<Student> Student) {
        List<StudentDto> studentDtos= new LinkedList<>();
        Iterator<Student> student= student.iterator();
        while (student.hasNext()) {
            Student student2= student.next();
            studentDtos.add(modelMapper.map(student2, StudentDTo.class));
        }
        return studentDtos;
    }
```

When i am doing this i am calling this in my controller and there i can see that Department DTo is coming as null. Can you tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `Student` list is not empty ?

Comment: please share `StudentDto` code

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi : I have updated the code plz check now

Comment: How you instantiate the `modelMapper`? Did you do some configuration on the `modelMapper` before call it in the code?

Comment: yes i have done the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

just change `StudentDto` to this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentDto{
     private int name;
     private Set<DepartmentDto> department;
}
```

or better naming may be:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student {
    private int name;
    private Set<Department> departments;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentDto {
    private int name;
    private Set<DepartmentDto> departments;
}
```